# counting genes: error: the combined objects have no sequence levels in common

Tags: r, rna-seq

I am new in processing RNA-seq data. I have human RNA-seq data and am now trying to count the genes using summarizeoverlaps, but I get this warning for all my files:

" In .Seqinfo.mergexy(x, y) :
  The 2 combined objects have no sequence levels in common. (Use
  suppressWarnings() to suppress this warning.)"

This is what I did:
I aligned my RNA seq files to the an Ensembl reference file (Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.cdna.all.fa.gz) and generated BAM files.

```
seqinfo(bamfiles)`

Seqinfo object with 190508 sequences from an unspecified genome:
  seqnames          seqlengths isCircular genome
  ENST00000633009.1         20       <NA>   <NA>
  ENST00000634070.1         18       <NA>   <NA>
  ENST00000632963.1         20       <NA>   <NA>
  ENST00000633030.1         19       <NA>   <NA>
  ENST00000633765.1         31       <NA>   <NA>
  ...                      ...        ...    ...
  ENST00000638565.1       1331       <NA>   <NA>
  ENST00000673346.1        895       <NA>   <NA>
  ENST00000673247.1        369       <NA>   <NA>
  ENST00000672305.1        758       <NA>   <NA>
  ENST00000671911.1        943       <NA>   <NA>
```

I also downloaded the GTF file from Ensembl:
Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.100.gtf.gz

```
seqinfo(txdb)
Seqinfo object with 47 sequences (1 circular) from an unspecified genome; no seqlengths:
  seqnames   seqlengths isCircular genome
  1                <NA>       <NA>   <NA>
  2                <NA>       <NA>   <NA>
  3                <NA>       <NA>   <NA>
  4                <NA>       <NA>   <NA>
  5                <NA>       <NA>   <NA>
  ...               ...        ...    ...
  KI270731.1       <NA>       <NA>   <NA>
  KI270733.1       <NA>       <NA>   <NA>
  KI270734.1       <NA>       <NA>   <NA>
  KI270744.1       <NA>       <NA>   <NA>
  KI270750.1       <NA>       <NA>   <NA>
```

I am guessing it has something to do with the seqnames, but I am not sure what I have to do. I tried converting it to Ensembl-style:
mapSeqlevels(seqlevels(bamfiles), "Ensembl")
mapSeqlevels(seqlevels(txdb), "Ensembl")
but that did no do anything...

NB featurecounts does not work either...

Thanks in advance!
Sandra

Comment: Forgot to mention that I am using R for this (version 3.6.3)

Comment: you aligned to transcripts, so the reference names are the transcript names. The gtf you have imported is based on the genome, the references are chromosomes. If you need transcript counts, you just need to count the reads falling on each transcript